# How to use jQuery AJAX $.post to store PHP $_SESSION variables?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, session

Help!

I'm having trouble wrestling AJAX to work for me. I have a paginated gallery with checkboxes beneath each image and I need to store the checkbox values in session variables if a user moves between the pages, so when they submit the form at any time it will include all checked values across all pages.

I'm using this jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".gal-nav").click(function() {
        $.post("form-data-holder.php", $("#gallery-form").serialize());
    });
});
```

and the form-data-holder.php file says this:

```
<?php

    $_SESSION['saved'] = "true";

    foreach ($_POST as $key=>$value ) {
        if ( $key !== "submit" ) {
            $value = htmlentities(stripslashes(strip_tags($value)));
            $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
        }
    }

?>
```

I have two issues --

1) How do I get the checkbox values out of the serialize() function? I think there's more I have to do with something like value[] to get that array out, and then I guess store each one as a separate session variable -- unless I can store an array as a $_SESSION variable?

2) Before I even mess with any of that, I added that line $_SESSION['saved'] = "true"; to the php script and then I echo the $_SESSION keys and values on my gallery page to see if the AJAX request is even working. It's not. That $_SESSION['saved'] isn't added to the list of echoed $_SESSION variables when I return to the page.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 6):

You need to call session_start() in your form-data-holder.php file.

Every time you make the ajax call, you are requesting a new / fresh page from the server that isn't aware of any of the variables set in the original page.

Comment: Sorry, the session has already been started by the fact that the user must be logged in to see the gallery at all.

Comment: Yes, but when you make an ajax call, it's loading a new php page, starting fresh, so you will need to call it there as well.

Comment: Hmm ok I added <?php session_start(); ?> to the top of the form-data-holder.php file -- no change. Do I have to associate that session with the other session somehow?

Comment: Not normally, if you're not starting the session in a special way with a session name or anything. Are you sure form-data-holder.php is opened / found?

Comment: No, not sure -- that seems to be the problem. But I've tried writing out the whole "http://..." address and it still doesn't work. Does it need to be a path?

Comment: Can you access you error log to check if it gives a file-not-found error?

Comment: I've actually never done that so I'm not sure.

I finally got it working though, so it's seeing the file -- however I'm now getting a lot of NOTICE: Undefined index for any of the $_POST variables that were left blank. I assume that's not a problem once I turn the error reporting off. I'm also still unable to access the checkbox array variables so I won't be able to set the session yet.

Comment: I'd personally add the necessary checks (if (isset(...))) instead of turning error reporting off. What is the problem with the session exactly?

Comment: You can disable error displaying and enable error logging to a file. It's practically a requirement for a live code.