# Save jQuery variables in a PHP session

Tags: php, jquery

```
var x = e.pageX;
var y = e.pageY;
```

Which is the easiest way to save those jQuery variables in a PHP session.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use jQuery AJAX $.post to store PHP $_SESSION variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1572888/how-to-use-jquery-ajax-post-to-store-php-session-variables)

Comment: @michael Why link to a question which has no accepted or obvious answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
   url: '/update-session.php',
   data: {"x":e.pageX,"y":e.pageY},
   type: 'post',
   success:function(data){
       // if you care. 
   }
});
```

update-session.php:

```
$_SESSION['pageX'] = $_POST['x'];
$_SESSION['pageY'] = $_POST['y'];
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: No they couldn't. The session keys are declared in the PHP file.

Comment: Dude, look at the code. JavaScript is not setting the session keys.

Answer (score 1):

Make an AJAX request to a PHP page that saves them in the session.