# Writing html textfield value to PHP Session possible without refresh?

Tags: php, forms, session

I want to be able to write some data to the PHP session AFTER the page has loaded, and BEFORE the page proceeds to the next page.

for example, this is a PHP file:

```
<input type="text" value="abc" />
<input type="button" onClick="doSomething()" />
```

How do I write "abc" to the php session (or whatever the user has typed in the textfield) in the javascript function doSomething()? Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use ajax to pass the value to php while the page is open

this was on the "related" sidebar on the right, for reference [How to use jQuery AJAX $.post to store PHP $_SESSION variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1572888/how-to-use-jquery-ajax-post-to-store-php-session-variables)

Comment: Thank you, but is using AJAX the only way? Since the php has finished executing at loading time, I guess it is not possible to execute any php without refreshing the page right?

Comment: php is only executing against a request. with ajax you send a request while the page is open. else, you have to wait until page refresh/reload